# Send 100,000 UDP Packets to Client (C Socket Programming)

Tags: c, sockets, udp

I'm working on a cool project and I need to send 100,000 UDP Packets from a Server to a Client with a Packet-to-Packet Delay of 10ms. The Server is Debian Server with a public IP Address. The Client is an other Debian PC with LTE USB-Modem. The Client has no public IP Address and knows the public IP Address of my Server. My 4G/LTE Provider doesn't provide public IP Adresses to thier clients.
I need to build a stable UDP Socket Connection but I'm struggling keeping the socket connection alive.

Can somebody help me?

thx

best regards

```
/**** CLIENT ****/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

#define PORT 20009

int main()
{
        int sock;
        int size;
        int nbytes, flags;
        int i;
        int a = 0;
        char * cp;
        char buffer[] = "012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789";

        struct sockaddr_in target_pc, me;

        sock = socket(PF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);
        if(sock < 0)
        {
                printf("socket error = %d\n", sock);
                return -1;
        }

        target_pc.sin_family = PF_INET;
        target_pc.sin_port = htons(PORT);

        me.sin_family = PF_INET;
        me.sin_port = htons(0);
        me.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
        i = bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &me, sizeof(me));

        if( i < 0)
        {
                printf("bind result: %d\n", i);
                return -1;
        }

        nbytes = 200;
        char str_addr[] = "155.55.25.25";
        target_pc.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(&str_addr[0]);

        while(1)
        {
                nbytes = strlen(buffer);
                flags = 0;
                sendto(sock, (char *) buffer, nbytes,flags,(struct sockaddr *)&target_pc,sizeof(target_pc));
                int addrlen = sizeof(target_pc);
                size = recvfrom(sock, buffer, nbytes, flags, (struct sockaddr *)&target_pc,&addrlen);

                if((size > 0) && (size < 200))
                {
                        buffer[size] = '\0';
                        i = puts((char *) buffer);
                }
                printf("%i --- Size: %lu\n", a, sizeof(buffer));
                a = a + 1;

        }
        return 0;
}
```

Below my Server Code:

```
/*** SERVER ***/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#define PORT 20009

void SleepMs(int ms)
{
    usleep(ms*1000); //convert to microseconds
    return;
}

int main()
{
        int sock;
        int size;
        int nbytes, flags;
        socklen_t addrlen;

        int i;

        char buffer[100];
        char buffer2[] = "12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890\0";
        struct sockaddr_in server;
        struct sockaddr_in from;

        sock = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);
        if(sock < 0)
        {
                printf("socket error = %d\n", sock);
                return -1;
        }
        server.sin_family = AF_INET;
        server.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

        server.sin_port = htons(PORT);

        i = bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &server, sizeof(server));

                if( i < 0){
                printf("bind result: %d\n", i);
                return -1;
        }
        else{
                printf("Simple UDP server is ready!\n");
        }

        nbytes = 200;
        flags = 0;

        while(1)
        {
                addrlen = sizeof(from);
                size = recvfrom(sock, buffer, nbytes, flags, (struct sockaddr *)&from, &addrlen);


                if((size > 0) && (size < 200))
                {
                        buffer[size] = '\0';
                        i = puts((char *) buffer);
                }
                printf("\n");
                sock = socket(PF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);
                if(sock < 0)
                {
                        printf("socket error = %d\n", sock);
                        return -1;
                }

                sendto(sock, buffer2, nbytes, flags, (struct sockaddr *)&from,addrlen);
                SleepMs(10); // Packet-to-Packet Delay Time
      }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you possibly use a TCP connection instead?  UDP hasn't any protocol-level sense of a connection by which a firewall could be expected to recognize that data coming from your server are responsive to a request from your client.

Comment: There is no such thing as a UDP Socket Connection,, certainly not something that must be "kept alive". Are you just getting a lot of dropped packets or something?

Comment: I need to work with UDP. Sorry... Socket Connection for UDP Packets-transmission is right thx

Comment: I'm not getting a lot of packets dropped. My Code is not good enough  because the server and the client are sending packets at the same time to each other to keep the connection open. There better solutions for this kind of job for sure

Comment: You need the delay between packets to be <= 10ms to keep the (application) connection alive, and right now you're getting delay between packets > 10ms?

Comment: After the transmission of 1019 packets the socket connection is dropped. Result : "socket error = -1".  I used 8 ms as delay time between packets.

Comment: You are leaking filedescriptors (one per message received/sent) in the server code.

Comment: Forget about the idea of a "socket connection". There is no such thing, period. The "socket error = -1" is something else and has nothing to do with any imaginary "connections". Just because there is an error doesn't mean that mythical creatures are involved (your approach was as if it was mythos). Please print out the full error message.

Comment: Your approach is also wide open to spoofing, even inadvertent spoofing. The server should be sending something that the client can verify to originate at the server, without any doubt. Perhaps the server should be sending a random value (say 256 bits long), and a sequence number (say 64 bits long), and then a cryptographic signature of the preceding. The client can verify the signature against server's public key, as well as ensure that the values are not reused. Only then it can trust the public IP address the packet came from, and start replying to it. Everything else should be ignored.

Comment: You can also run a TCP/IP stack on top of UDP (say [uIP from Contiki](https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/tree/master/core/net/ip)), and then run something secure like a [TLS 1.3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) connection. The "UDP only" approach is unnecessary. The connection will be as stable as your LTE connection, and it will be trustworthy. Anything less seems very dubious to me. Why do you want those connections to begin with? And why do you insist on UDP? Might as well use TCP/IP directly.

Comment: 'Struggling to keep the connection alive' is completely meaningless, for the reasons given by @yano and KubaOber, as is 'socket connection for UDP'. 'Socket error ==  -1' is merely an error *indication.* It means that you should retrieve `errno` or call `perror()` or `strerror()` to determine the *actual* error. Please do so and provide, in your question, the *actual* error you are experiencing.

Answer (score -1):

You can have the connection using IP of the server in this case 192.168.1.2

server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.1.2");

using this in both codes